# Remove left nav from single category page

Tags: magento-1.9, category, layout

I am looking to remove the left hand navigation from the top level category pages. I attempted the following xml in layout updates within the category section of admin panel but unfortunately it had no effect.

```
         <remove name="catalog.leftnav"/>
```

Here's the catalog.xml reference that I believe calls this nav - I've even tried commenting out the xml but the nav still displays.

```
              <label>Catalog Category (Anchor)</label>
    <reference name="left_first">
        <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="catalog.leftnav.state.renderers" as="state_renderers" />
        </block>
    </reference>
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `reference` there. Try:

```
<reference name="left">
    <remove name="catalog.leftnav"/>
</reference>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that still didn't work - very odd! I am using RWD theme - I presume this wouldn't make a difference?

Comment: Any thoughts Mayers please?

Comment: Very odd indeed, I have tried it myself and it worked. Are you sure your left nav has this name? If you have a custom module for your layered navigation, they might have called it differently

Comment: Thanks for coming back - I've now included the XML in the first post...

Comment: See how your reference is "left_first" instead of "left". Replace that in the solution I gave you

Answer (score 0):

Please first check in your **xml** if the left navigation category block called: `name="catalog.leftnav"` and you dont renamed it. If it's ok you will remove this left category navigation in the the page that you want(the layout handle associate to this page) in `local.xml` like this:

```
<catalog_product_view> // here we remove the left catalog navigation just in product view page for exemple
   <reference name="left">
        <remove name="catalog.leftnav"/>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```